# Why does not the negative indices in python strings result as expected?

Tags: python, string, indices

I created a string in python : 'HelpA' and labeled it as word.

```
>>>word='HelpA'

>>>word

'HelpA' #expected string

>>>word[0:4]

'Help' #expected string
```

While calling the word with negative indices, I am getting the full string instead of partial string as expected.

```
>>>word[-97:]

'HelpA'  #not the expected string
```

Its giving the whole string instead of expected string : `'pA'` Why does this happen?

Comment: Why would you expect to get `pA` when indexing it with `[-97:]`?

Comment: Where do you come up with the value `-97`?

Comment: in your example `word[0:4] == 'Help'`, not `'help'`

Comment: `-1` is the last element in the string, `-2` is the second to last, etc., with `-5` being the first character. And `-6` is out of bounds. What character in the string would then have index `-97`?

Comment: @CarlesMitjans, since there are 5 characters in the word, and 97=5*19+2, I am expecting the last 2 characters.

Comment: @Babu: no, slicing indices do not wrap; they are instead bounded by the actual string indices. `len(word) - 97` is `-92`, which is then bound by the actual starting index `0`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I now tried with >>> word[-100:]
'HelpA'
>>> word[-99:]
'HelpA', Can u please explain it further?

Comment: @Babu: negative indices are subtracted from `len(word)`. If that index then falls outside of the bounds, they are replaced by the bounds. For the start index, with a positive stride (the default), that means they are set to `0`. All those huge negative indices in the first position simply are replaced by `0`. `word[0:]` is the whole string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd say negative indices are **added** to `len(word)`.

Comment: @Babu: note that that subtraction only applies **once**. So `len(word) - 97` becomes `-92`. That is then *not treated as a relative index again*, it is simply out of bounds.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: yeah, mathematically speaking, it is `len(word) + -97`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you expect the negative index to 'wrap'. (97 % len(word) == 2).

It doesn't :)

This example shows you why:

```
>>> word[-1:]
'A'
>>> word[-3:]
'lpA'
>>> word[-5:]
'HelpA'
>>> word[-10:]
'HelpA'
```

When the negative index goes beyond the length of the string, it will be truncated. [This](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) section of the Python documentation explains explains it like this:

> The slice of s from i to j is defined as the sequence of items with index k such that i <= k < j

This code does the equivalent slicing (for strings):

```
def slice(s, i, j):
    sliced = []
    for k, item in enumerate(s):
        if i <= k and k < j:
            sliced.append(item)
    return ''.join(sliced)
```

Output:

```
>>> slice('foo', -100, 2)
'fo'
>>> 'foo'[-100:2]
'fo'
```

This should make it clear why `word[-100:]` and `word[-99:]` gives the same result: **all characters in the string have a position or index larger than -100 or -99, since 0 is the first position of the string**

Comment: Please explain in this case as well : >>> word[-100:]
'HelpA'
>>> word[-99:]
'HelpA'

Comment: Or what should be the expected string?

Comment: @Babu I have updated the answer with an example. I hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

**You're asking for the last 97 characters.** There aren't that many, but Python plays nice and just gives you as much as it can, which is the last 5 characters (i.e., all).